# How to order by date when the column is not date formatted?

Tags: sql-server

The database I'm querying has a user table with a column containing the date the user registered for a website.

The date is entered into a varchar column without proper date formatting like this:

```
Apr 18 2013 12:27PM
```

When I `SELECT MAX (dateColumn)` I get a value roughly half way across the range of dates. I've considered using substrings to  grab the year, then the month, then the date and order them in sequence. The problem is that dates with days starting with a  0 will be *shortened* by one character like this:

```
May 1 2013 12:27PM
```

**Is there a simple way to find the highest date, without altering the database structure?**

Comment: You should never store dates in a varchar column. And your problem is a direct result of that error. I would highly recommend to change the column to a real `DateTime` and migrate the data.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it wasn't me that made the website/db. As there are already 200+ users I can't alter the database.

Comment: Of course you can. Add a new column, migrate the data from the old column to the new column. Drop the old column. Adjust your application. This is standard schema migration (which you need to have in place anyway) and the number of users has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `select max(convert(datetime, dateColumn, 109))`

Further information on converting between datatypes in SQLServer (including date formats) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: What does the 109 signify?

Comment: @JackDamery: The third argument is the format to use when converting from a character field to a date field; 109 means mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM (or PM) - you could also use 100, instead. You can see a full list of date formats and further information on converting between datatypes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Cast the column to have the values in the format "YYYYMMDD" then sort that column.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting varchar to datetime format and do. You should save date in same format. Its just example to convert varchar to datetime.

```
Select * from tblName 
    where Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(12),DOJ,106)) as DOJ >=
          Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(12),'2013-04-28',106))
```